# Disabling sensor batching in Android 4.4

Tags: android

Is there any way to disable batching of sensor results (from my application's code) in Android 4.4?

I am aware it might not be the best idea, but I am also sure it's worthy in my app's case despite of higher battery consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rateUs, int maxBatchReportLatencyUs)
```

then you enable sensor batching. if you call the older version:

```
registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rateUs, Handler handler)
```

Then sensor batching shouldn't occur.
Another workaround that could work:

When using the `SensorManager`, call `getFifoMaxEventCount()` to get the maximum number of sensor events it can save, and divide that number by the rate at which your app desires each event. Use that calculation to set wake alarms with `AlarmManager` that invoke your Service (which implements the `SensorEventListener`) to flush the sensor.

also look here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#BatchSensors

Comment: Isn't passing 0 as maxBatchReportLatencyUs sufficient?

Comment: Well according to this: [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/hardware/SystemSensorManager.java#SystemSensorManager.BaseEventQueue.addSensor%28android.hardware.Sensor%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) your suggestion will not work (the sensor will be removed from the sensors queue). However parts of the code are native and I can't tell for sure.